# Transform co-circular stadium view into a omnivision (planar) view

Tags: camera, transformation, hough-transform, fisheye

Imagine a stadium (e.g. football) with an omnivision (fisheye) camera on top, centered.
You'll get a picture, wich will give you an almost planar view of the field.

Now comes a second camera setup:
You have the same stadium, but with normal (no fisheye) cameras in the top, four corners, pointing on the field.

Now here comes the question:
Is there a transformation between these two camera setups?

I thought of a Hough transformation, to get a planar view of the field with the second camera setup. Am I heading into the right direction or do you have any other ideas to get a planar view?

Answer (score 0):

Ok basically you can create the fisheye effect by just making multiple picuteres and transform them accordingly, stitching is the way to go http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

However with a fisheye ontop a football field you will not get a planar view of the field. A planar view you get if you move your camera up the z-Axis till infinity! So it's rather a zoom.

Am I right and you really want to create a minimap from a football field? Then the Hough Transformation is good to recognize the field on the pictures, and calculate the different camera positions, but you still need to transform the pixels in the pictures to become a planar view. To get sth. that looks like a picture.

Comment: I thought of stitching, too. But the images will have very big overlapping areas, so only the edges need to be stitched. The problem is to merge the overlapping areas as best as possible to create the (you named it) minimap. I have not found any similar problem/solution, which is related to mine.

Comment: Given you have the positions of the lines and corners on the picture, it shouldn't be hard to get actual field coordinates of a planar view. I'll have to think about it, but when the cameras are height enought there shouldn't be a problem with sth that flat like a field.